# What's word means someone who VOLUNTARILY isolates themself from society?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I know there are words like *[outcast](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=outcast), [pariah](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=pariah), [ostracized](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=ostracized), [leper](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=leper),* etc. to describe someone who is shunned by society. I’m looking for a word to describe someone who rejects society and lives detached from society.

Furthermore, I thought of [*hermit*](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=hermit) but there are religious connotations to the word and while I am aware that it can be used to describe what I said I would prefer a word with a more neutral connotation. Also, I don’t want to limit myself to just a noun for this. Adjectives or verbs that can be used to describe voluntary detachment from society work as well.

Comment: Uhm, so did you look up hermit? Did you find any synonyms? What was wrong with them?

Comment: Lol I didn’t think to do that I found a word called solitudinarian and it works. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I liked recluse.

Comment: *Hermit* seems perfectly reasonable to me. Barring some reason why it's not acceptable (I have never heard it used in a religious sense—even though I just discovered that's mentioned in [a definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hermit)), I suggest that the answer has already been given in the question. And the definition I looked up does mention *recluse*, whose own definition mentions nothing about religion.